# Unable to run JavaScript in Modal froms in SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have multiple lines of JavaScript codes running in a Survey form "editForm.aspx". When I browse editForm.aspx directly it works well, but when I open the form by clicking 'respond to this survey' the dialog modal form opens and the JS code dos not run.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure your javascript at right location.

you should move you code inside

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
```

e.g

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderTitleAreaClass" runat="server">
<script id="onetidPageTitleAreaFrameScript">
document.getElementById("onetidPageTitleAreaFrame").className="ms-areaseparator";
</script>
</asp:Content>
```